# How Can I Setup A .htaccess File That Will Redirect To A Sub Directory Containing Index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

**Here Is My File Structure** 
[image]

*Requests to the root directory should automatically redirect to `Dist->index.php`* 
Any unrecognized files/directories should also redirect to index.php. Normally I'd be able to accomplish this, however, I always get Forbidden 403 access. I've also tried changing httpd.conf access to allow overrides but had no success with that. The closest I've gotten is being able to redirect to index.php from within the same directory it is in if there are unrecognized files.

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dist/index.php [L,QSA]
_____________________
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Dist/index.php [L]
_____________________
RewriteBase /src/
```

Comment: Well, there are many, many answers to this question here on SO. They are valid. So if you say that "I Saw A Similar Question But No It Did Not Answer What I Need", then the question is why does it work for others, but not for you? Just repeating the question won't result in another answer obviously. So there is no sense in us answering here. You'd need to say where your situation is different from all others where the existing answers _do_ work.

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` file in the root directory or in the `dist` directory?

Comment: You now state that you get a 403. That has nothing to do with rewriting. Either you have further rules implemented which you did not show here, probably in the central condiguration of that http server, or your application logic serves that 403. We cannot say.

Comment: What URLs are you requesting? What is the document root? From your file structure, it looks like the `.htaccess` file is inside the `Dist` subdirectory? That is certainly incorrect unless `/Dist` is part of the URL or `/Dist` is the document root? "I always get Forbidden 403" - You shouldn't "always" be getting a 403 (do you not get 404s as well?), which could perhaps suggest a more fundamental server config issue? "I've also tried changing httpd.conf access to allow overrides but had no success with that." - `.htaccess` overrides certainly need to be enabled as a first step.